# Why was the warning about % formatting toned down in newer Python docs?

Tags: python, documentation

The [Python 3.1.5 docs](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations) refer to the `%` style formatting as "Old String Formatting Operations" and provide this warning that it may be removed:

> **Note:** The formatting operations described here are obsolete and may go away in future versions of Python. Use the new *[String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/string.html#string-formatting)* in new code.

The replacement section appears to be [`printf`-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3//library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) . It contains this warning:

> **Note:** The formatting operations described here exhibit a variety of quirks that lead to a number of common errors (such as failing to display tuples and dictionaries correctly). Using the newer [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3//library/stdtypes.html#str.format) interface helps avoid these errors, and also provides a generally more powerful, flexible and extensible approach to formatting text.

So it is still clearly discouraged, but why was the note about possibly removing the feature cut from the docs? Was this some sort of policy decision or enforcement, since it's not officially deprecated yet? Are there still plans to eventually deprecate and remove it?

Comment: What prevents you from simply using the new String Formatting operations?

Comment: Note that 3.5 *expanded* the use of the `%` operator by adding it to the `bytes` and `bytearray` classes ([PEP 461](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0461/)), so it seems like there are no plans to remove it any time soon.

Comment: See also http://bugs.python.org/issue25407

Comment: @RobertHarvey Nothing. I prefer it. I'm wondering why the discouragement was relaxed. My question was prompted by someone suggesting that it's *not* discouraged, so I went looking for proof. I found a link to the 3.1.5 version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12382738/1394393) and tried to find the newer equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Despite `%` deprecation, a huge amount of code, including for Python 3, still uses `%` instead of `format()`. Why? Partially because of the old habits, and partially because developers find that `%` is perfectly fine for their needs—frankly, as soon as it is used like this:

```
"Available quantity: %s." % (123,)
```

instead of:

```
"Available quantity: %s." % 123
```

it works pretty well: it may be ugly according to some people, but not any more risky than `format()`.

As soon as a feature is broadly used, it can be depreciated, but can hardly be removed, at least from Python 2 and Python 3. Maybe Python 4 won't have it. Who knows.

Does it mean that it will always be available in Python 2 and Python 3? Maybe yes. Maybe no. It might happen that the usage of `%` would drastically drop in a few years, meaning that it could be removed without causing too much trouble.

Should you continue using it? No. `format()` is a superior alternative, so there are no reasons to stick with `%` in new codebases. If you're contributing to an old codebase which consistently uses `%`, stick with it: uniformity matters.

Comment: I disagree with the last sentence. I'm working on a codebase that used `%`, but the other developers and I have all started using `format()`, and replacing the old-style with the new-style when it's convenient. I think making a gradual change like this is fine.

Comment: @gardenhead: exactly! I was talking about a case where you're a new contributor, for instance in an open source project. But if the whole team can decide that it's time to move to `format()`, then do it, absolutely.

Comment: For comparison, the last time Python made a backwards-incompatible change to such a popularly-used operator (`/` on `int`s), it was phased in over a period of 7 years (`from __future__ import division` in 2.2 (2001) to forcing the new behavior in 3.0 (2008)).